# Extending a vector bundle to a torsion free sheaf

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Let's say that $X$ is an integral scheme of finite type over a field and $Y \subset X$ is a closed subscheme.  Given a vector bundle $E$ on $Y$, is $E$ the restriction to $Y$ of a vector bundle on a neighborhood $U$ of $Y$ in $X$?

Comment: Isn't this exactly the Leff(X,Y) condition?  This is true if $Y$ is a complete intersection of dimension at least 2 in a smooth projective variety $X$.  Given $E$ on $Y$, you take $\hat{E}$ on the completion $\hat{X}$ of $X$ along $Y$, and Leff(X,Y) allows you to lift it to a bundle $E'$ in a neighborhood of $Y$ in $X$.

Comment: What is Leff(X,Y)?

Comment: Ok, I found it.  Even if the pair (X,Y) does not satisfy Leff, is there a way to understand when E on Y extends to a bundle on the formal completion?  Some kind of obstruction perhaps to extending to various infinitesimal thickenings of Y...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, this is not even true for line bundles.

For an example, let $X = \mathbb{P}^2$ and $Y$ a smooth curve in $X$ of genus $>0$ (over an algebraically closed field). Since $X$ is smooth, any line bundle on an open set $U$ extends to a line bundle on $X$ so the map $\operatorname{Pic}(X) \to \operatorname{Pic}(U)$ is surjective.  Since $\operatorname{Pic}(X) \cong \mathbb{Z}$, it follows that the image of $\operatorname{Pic}(U)$ in $\operatorname{Pic}(Y)$ is of rank $1$ and is independent of $U \supset Y$. Since $\operatorname{Pic}(Y)$ is not even finitely generated we see that there exist (many) line bundles on $Y$ which do not extend to any open $U \supset Y$.